# Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) + Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)

Tags: wpf, wif, adfs

Scenario:  I need to configure a WPF application to send credentials from integrated security to an ADFS server and receive tokens back.  I can't find guides describing in detail how to do this.  The focus seems to be on web applications, web services, & WCF.

What are the steps to configure a WPF client?  Is it possible to setup through a config file the same way a web app is configured?

Answer (score 5):

You want to implement an Active WS-Trust scenario. Follow Lab 4 - **Federation with ADFS with "active" clients"** from here: http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/68061 .

If you chose to call ADFS manually to get tokens follow **WIF, ADFS 2 and WCF Article Series** by Dominick Baier here: http://leastprivilege.com/2010/10/14/wif-adfs-2-and-wcfpart-5-service-client-more-flexibility-with-wstrustchannelfactory/

Both of those resources have helped me to implement Active WIF Scenario.